# Scala. Data frame how to name change the one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataframe:

```
ID       Name       key
1        Cuz        333
2.       Zzzz       666
```

How to convert the column `key` as `key2`?

My output should be like below,

```
ID       Name       key2
1        Cuz        333
2.       Zzzz       666
```

Comment: What is the type of inputs and outputs?

Comment: The question as asked has no Scala in it. You should rephrase with some relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **use `.withColumnRenamed`** as

```
df.withColumnRenamed("key", "key2")
```

**or use `.withColumn` and `drop` the `key` column** as

```
df.withColumn("key2", $"key").drop("key")
```

**or use `select` and `alias`** as

```
df.select($"ID", $"Name", $"key".alias("key2"))
```

or

```
df.select($"ID", $"Name", $"key".as("key2"))
```

Comment: @lak didn't the answer helped you ? If it did , would you mind considering upvote and accepting . It would help me if you do :)